Animation based on card game
Does anybody know the animation series name which is based on the concept of a card game in which monsters come out of cards when the card is called. This show is similar to "Yu-Gi-Oh!" but not based on an ancient prince story, its story is based on a dimension where these card creatures live and the unbalance of this and our dimension.
A boy starts his journey to become a master in the game and find his father. He got his father's "card" which got a creature called 'volmetious dragon' or smilar. One friend (girl) helps the boy to get through the journey and she has some mysterious power in her. 
I also remember one card creature got a snake head and has the ability to run faster and it got blades at the back side of the elbow.

I think I just stumbled across the actual answer to your question while researching someone else's question.
Duel Masters- ran on Cartoon Network in the US 2002-03, originated in Japan as a manga then an anime series.
Bolded parts match your description.
Plot Summary:

The anime is about a boy named Shobu Kirifuda who plays a game called
  "Duel Masters" which revolves around the five civilizations (Light,
  Water, Darkness, Fire, Nature). In the early volumes of the manga
  series, he plays the Magic: The Gathering card game instead.
In Duel Masters, there are 2 worlds that are featured.
There is the real world of Earth in which the main characters live, as
  well as the creature world in which the civilizations are at war
  against each other.  By using a fictional martial art called "Kaijudo"
  (known as the "Duel of Truth" in the Japanese version) the players can
  bring the monsters to life and appear in their duels.
In the later Victory seasons of the anime, the outer space of the
  creature world is known as "Pandora Space" and from there has been
  appearances of different creature races appearing into the real world.
  Facing these creatures is Katta Kirifuda, Shobu's younger brother.

Shobu Kirifuda

The show's protagonist and Knight's apprentice. He aspires to become a
  great duelist like his father, Shori Kirifuda. Shobu keeps a positive
  attitude throughout the series, insisting on dueling for fun as
  opposed to simply winning. In the first season, Shobu takes on the
  challenge of defeating the temple champion, Hakuoh, who he feels has
  become corrupt with power. Throughout this portion of the series,
  Shobu must defeat Hakuoh's underlings while he struggles to understand
  the true spirit of dueling. In his duel with Hakuoh, as Shobu faces
  off against the strongest of all Angel Commands, he is forced to make
  a crucial decision. He must either accept the help of his friends and
  "wind up like Ko" (Kokujo having been injured in a Kaihudo duel) or
  give up on his friends and "end up like Hakuoh", who had become cold
  and heartless. All in all Shobu is brave, strong, and has the guts
  never to give up, just like his favorite creatures. He uses a Fire
  Civilization deck which later becomes a Dragon Deck and even later
  evolves into a Dragon/Angel Command deck. After being defeated in a
  later season he loses most of his deck but is guided to his father's
  deck by the spirits of Bolmeteus Samurai Dragon and Bolbalzak "Sword
  Flash" Dragon. This new deck is a Dragon and Samurai deck. Soon after
  he combined elements from the 2 decks and created a Samurai
  Dragon/Angel Command deck (Fire, Light & Nature civilizations). As of
  Duel Masters Cross his main cards are: Bolmeteus "Kensei" Dragon,
  Bolshack Yamato Dragon, Bolbalzak "Sword Flash" Dragon and Saint
  Bolshack, Spiritual Dragon.


thanks for answer and plz up question if you think it is useful :)

Bakugan? 

Dan Kuso's life changed one day when random cards fell out of the sky,
  where he and his friend Shun invented a game with called Bakugan.
Together with his friends Runo, Marucho, Julie, Shun, and Alice, the
  group Bakugan Battle Brawlers is formed and its members are
  accidentally dragged into fighting for the fate of Vestroia (the
  Bakugan's home dimension) against the Doom Beings.
It is the story of a dimension called Vestroia which loses its natural
  balance and merges with the Earth and many other alien planets. An
  evil Bakugan called Naga was tempted and decided to take the Silent
  Core. So Dan and his friends decided to bring back balance by meeting
  new friends and allies in the other planets, learn more about the
  origin of the Bakugan; and facing Naga, who seeks to complete the
  Perfect Core.

Dan Kuso:

The main protagonist in the series, Dan is a boy who loves playing
  Bakugan and gets frustrated easily. His greatest ambition is to be the
  number one battle brawler in the world. Dan is a Pyrus battler, and
  his Guardian Bakugan is a Pyrus-attribute Dragonoid (nicknamed
  Drago)(voiced by Keiji Fujiwara). His Drago loves Wavern, who holds
  the Infinity Core within her. Dan and Runo often argue with each
  other; Dan likes Runo but doesn't confess until the end of the series,
  when they are seen on a date together.



cardfight vanguard!!
this is the best anime card game ever!must watch.This anime is about a boy name aichi WHO IS A LONER AND WANTS TO GET SOME FRIENDS.AND THEN HE STARTS PLAYING THIS GAME which totally changes his whole life and finds himself a whole bunch of friends.This anime has i think 4 seasons.

You need to elaborate on how this series fits with the items the asker has noted in their question. Simply throwing out a show and then raving bout how much you love it does not a good answer make.
